# Eddystone-EID - what is it for and does it work?

Tags: beacon, eddystone

Simply put, how does Eddystone-EID work and what are the main use cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard beacons transmit a unique identifier so apps can tell when they are in a particular place.  But because this identifier is in clear text, any app can read this identifier, and use the transmission to know where it is.  **An unauthorized third party app can make use of standard beacons that the app's authors did not deploy.**

**Eddystone-EID encrypts it's identifier and rotates it periodically to prevent others from making use of the beacon identifier.**  Authorized apps can use a "trusted resolver" to get a stable identifier from the rotating encrypted one in the transmission.  A server call is needed to convert the 8-byte AES encrypted identifier to a stable one.

Google's Proximity Beacon API provides this conversion.  It is theoretically possible to build an independent trusted resolver apart from Google (I have done so for testing purposes), but otherwise you must register your EID beacons with Google and use their web services to resolve their identifiers.

An example ephemeral identifier looks like this:

```
0a194f562c97d2ea.
```

Here's a write up I did on the topic: http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/eddystone-eid.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's an explanation I found on a *developers.google.com* page [here](https://developers.google.com/beacons/eddystone-eid).

> **What happens when a client sights an Eddystone-EID beacon?**
>
> When a client device sights an Eddystone-EID beacon as a result of a Nearby<sup>1</sup> subscription, the current EID is sent to the Google Proximity Beacon API<sup>2</sup> along with the API key of the calling app. The Google Proximity Beacon API establishes whether the supplied API key is authorized to fetch attachments that have been associated with the beacon. If resolution is allowed, the attachments are served back as Nearby message objects in the normal way. Otherwise, Google Proximity Beacon API returns an empty value, as it would if the beacon had not been registered.

<sup>1</sup> - The beacon scanning component of the Google beacon platform

<sup>2</sup> - The Proximity Beacon API is a cloud service that allows you to manage data associated with your BLE beacons using a REST interface.

Here's another paragraph which I found critical to understand how the technology works.

> Eddystone-EID is designed to give developers control over which clients can make use of their beacon signals. The beacon identifier changes pseudo-randomly in such a way that it can only be resolved to stable information by a resolution service that shares an encryption key with the beacon. Without access to the resolution service, the beacon identifier is of little use.
>
> Eddystone-EID is appropriate for cases where beacon deployers wish to:
>
> - Prevent other parties from using their beacons.
> - Preserve user privacy in scenarios involving wearables or other equipment carried by the user.
> - Lease their beacon network to other parties in a way that allows a provable 'off switch' for access.
> - Provide a strong signal that a user is at a particular place, that is not easily spoofed.